# Gatsby develop not working after creating a project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, gatsby, cypress

I created a Gatsby project and whenever I run `gatsby develop` or `npm run develop` I get the following error:

````
UNHANDLED REJECTION spawn node ENOENT

  Error: spawn node ENOENT

  - child_process:277 Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
    node:internal/child_process:277:19

  - child_process:477 onErrorNT
    node:internal/child_process:477:16

  - task_queues:81 processTicksAndRejections
    node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21


npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Code\Gatsby test project\gatsby-test
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c gatsby develop

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-21T10_50_22_321Z-debug.log```
````

Other scripts like `gatsby build` and `gatsby clean` work when I run them but that is not the case with `npm run develop` or `npm start`

Firstly, I tried to uninstall `node_modules` and delete `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` but I still got the error.
I tried to uninstall `gatsby-cli` and create a project with `npm init gatsby` but the was no difference again. Finally, I uninstalled Nodejs completely and installed the latest version but I still get the `Error: spawn node ENOENT` everytime I try to start the development server.

I have experience with React but I am new to Gatsby. I recently had a problem with my Node where running `npm start` did nothing and returned me to the console. The issue was that my Nodejs folder was installed in `D:\` and not in `C:\` drive and also `react-scripts` version was old but a simple reinstallation fixed the problem.

I haven't changed anything in the project but here is the `package.json` file:

```
  "name": "gatsby-starter-hello-world",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simplified bare-bones starter for Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "0BSD",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^2.26.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.2.1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

I would be grateful if somebody points me where the issue might be.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: This is a Node related issue. Can you debug a little bit more? What happen when running `node -v` on the root of the project? Maybe it's not in the correct path

Comment: It displays the latest version(v15.6.0) when I run `node -v` in the root. It shoud be the correct path as I `cd` into the folder after I created the project and run `npm run develop` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try downloading a fresh starter and try it again?

Comment: I am getting the same `Error: spawn node ENOENT`.

Comment: If it is a node related issue and I have reinstalled it a few times, is it a good idea to try to reinstall my operating system?

Comment: I hope it's not needed. It's really odd. I don't know how to help you because all stuff related to this issue points to Node. It seems to be properly installed. Gatsby's client, however, looks for the C path...

Comment: I tried to run `npm run develop:cypress` which I guess runs the scripts through yarn and it started the development server but I am still confused what is going on with my node. I guess I found a way around the problem so thank you for your time!

Comment: I've posted an answer if you don't mind, for all the rest that may help.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might be in the same trouble: the issue has been finally solved using:

```
npm run develop:cypress
```